# How to fetch AmazonMQ nodes for RabbitMQ brokers using API, CLI or Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, prometheus, amazon-mq

I'm trying to create AWS Cloudwatch alarm for `systemCpuUtilizaiton` of each RabbitMQ broker
nodes via Terraform. To create the [AWS Cloudwatch alarm](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_metric_alarm), I need to provide **dimensions** (node-name and broker) as mentioned in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/security-logging-monitoring-cloudwatch.html).

Hence, I'm looking to fetch the **rabbitMQ broker node-names** from AWS (via CLI, or API or Terraform)

Please note: I'm able to see the matrices of each broker nodes in AWS Cloudwatch console, but not from API, SDK or CLI.

I went through the below links but didn't get anything handy https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/mq/index.html#cli-aws-mq
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/mq_broker

Please let me know in case I'm missing something.

Comment: is this what you're looking for? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_metric_alarm

Comment: No, I am using "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" resource for creating the alarms, but to create that I need to provide "dimensions"(which will be the name of the node created by AWS for RabbitMQ broker)

Comment: You can reference other resources within TF. eg `dimensions = { Broker = aws_mq_broker.example.broker_name }`. I might still be confused on where you're having trouble.

Comment: If you refer to "RabbitMQ node metrics" section of the AWS docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/security-logging-monitoring-cloudwatch.html, there is two parameters needed(as dimensions): Node and Broker. I got the broker, but not the node names(on which the broker is running)

Comment: I understand the issue now. That's a tough one as it doesn't appear AWS exposes that through the API at all. You can access `aws_mq_broker.example.instances` which includes `ip_address`. You may be able to use that to construct the node hostname.

Comment: Also note that there is a `CpuUtilization` on the broker level which I assume is an average of all the nodes. That could be a more useful metric to alarm on.

Comment: Unfortunately, `CpuUtilization` is specific to `ActiveMQ`, there are no CPU matrices at the broker level for `RabbitMQ`.

Comment: Ah, bummer. Hopefully my answer works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have raised the above-mentioned problem to AWS support, below is the solution:

First of all response from AWS team, AmazonMQ-RabbitMQ broker nodes are managed internally by AWS and currently its not exposed via API or SDK.

As a result there is **NO way to fetch the Rabbit MQ broker node name** via API or SDK. *Hence its not possible to directly create cloudwatch alarm on Rabbit MQ broker node's `systemCpuUtilizaiton`*, [as node name are required dimensions for creating the alert](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/security-logging-monitoring-cloudwatch.html).

**There are two alternative solutions**

1. Query RabbitMQ API to fetch the node-name
2. Use [prometheus/cloudwatch-exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/cloudwatch_exporter), to fetch the matrices details from cloud watch where node names are available.

I have used the second method, below values file to fetch the matrices we are interested

```yaml
prometheus-cloudwatch-exporter:
    namespace: monitoring
    enabled: true
    override:
      metrics:
        alb: false
        rds: false
        # ... based on requirement
      alerts:
        ec2: false # based on requirement
      additionalMetrics: |-
        # below configuration will fetch the martics,
        # containing Rabbit MQ broker node names
        - aws_namespace: AWS/AmazonMQ
          aws_metric_name: SystemCpuUtilization
          aws_dimensions: [Broker, Node]
          aws_statistics: [Average]
```

If everything is configured correctly, you should be able to `aws_amazonmq_system_cpu_utilization_average` martic in prometheus as shown below. Now use Prometheus Alert manager to create alerts on top of this matrics.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Recently, AWS started publishing [CPU/Mem/Disk metrics per Broker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/security-logging-monitoring-cloudwatch.html#rabbitmq-logging-monitoring).

You should see these metrics under `AmazonMQ/Broker metrics`. You can now use the `SystemCpuUtilization` metric without a node name dimension and then take the Maximum statistic to get the most overloaded node. You can create a CloudWatch alarm based on this metric.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The AWS MQ node names used for the cloudwatch dimensions do not appear to be exposed through the AWS API, but the node name is predictable knowing the IP address. I believe this can be used to construct valid node names for alarms.

```
data "aws_region" "current" {}

resource "aws_mq_broker" "example" {
  ...
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "bat" {
  for_each = toset([
    for instance in aws_mq_broker.example.instances : instance.ip_address
  ])

  alarm_name          = "terraform-test-foobar5"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "2"
  metric_name         = "SystemCpuUtilization"
  namespace           = "AWS/AmazonMQ"
  period              = "120"
  statistic           = "Average"
  threshold           = "80"

  dimensions = {
    Broker = aws_mq_broker.example.name
    Node   = "rabbitmq@ip-${replace(each.value, ".", "-")}.${data.aws_region.current.name}.compute.internal"
  }
}
```

Comment: I did not have a setup to test this so I will be surprised if it works as-is, but I believe this is at least very close to a working solution

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying, but IP addresses are not returned, output values of `aws_mq_broker.example` looks something like this

"
....
BrokerInstances            = [
          {
              ConsoleURL = "https://b-2dce7324-02ga-414f-b6y0-99d986e78880.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
              Endpoints  = [
                   "amqps://b-2dce7324-02ga-414f-b6y0-99d986e78880.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:5671",
                ]
            },
        ]..." not sure its super readable, my point is there is no `ip_address` returned.